# Linux Kernel-Module loading with modprobe - needs reboot

Tags: linux, unix, modprobe

I was just playing around with the bios beep and therefore I had to load the module pcspkr.
But the beep would only work when I rebooted the system.
The module is definitely loaded, but the speaker driver is not working until rebooting the system.

Here is what I did:

```
$ modprobe pcspkr
$ lsmod | grep pcspkr
pcspkr                 12702  0
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

regards

Update:
Even suspending to RAM makes the bios beep work.

Comment: I guess that `pcspkr` depends on some other modules that were not loaded.

Comment: I'd rather say, one or more other modules must be unloaded before the speaker beeps. Can you bring your system to the state where it doesn't beep and then provide the complete output of `lsmod`?

Comment: @terdon: `modprobe` always inserts dependent modules first.

Comment: @grawity yes, but I was imagining some strange situations with blacklisted modules. Not at all sure it is possible but if the blacklist has been read and a module banned and then one that requires the banned one is loaded, will the blacklisting be ignored?

Comment: no, i dont think so; btw: originally the pcspkr module was blacklisted on my system, but i removed it from the blacklist